# For what reason I get the "request for member ... in ... which is of non-class type ..." error in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constructor-injection, most-vexing-parse

I've found a tricky (at least for me :D) issue in the following code:

```
class Beta
{
    public:
        Beta(double d)
        {
            value = d;
        }
        double getValue() const
        {
            return value;
        }
    private:
        double value;
};

class Alpha
{

    public:
        Alpha(const Beta& beta)
        {
            value = beta.getValue();
        }

        Alpha(double d)
        {
            Alpha alpha(Beta(d));
            value = alpha.value;
        }

        private:
            double value;
};

int main()
{
    Alpha(5);
}
```

changing "Alpha alpha(Beta(d));" with one of the followings, will make the code compile:

- Alpha alpha(Beta(5));
- Alpha alpha(Beta((double)d));
- Alpha alpha{Beta{d}};  //valid for c++11

The compliler error I get is: 
"request for member 'value' in 'alpha', which is of non-class type 'Alpha(Beta)' "

I'd expect such an error in cases like:

```
Alpha a();
a.value;
```

but since it didn't happen here, I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, the setup is more complicated but it is still the same: `Alpha alpha(Beta(d));` declares a function.

Comment: [*warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration \[-Wvexing-parse\]*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9379f33d026d95f)

Comment: How it could declare a function If I pass the 'd' variable (which contains 5) to 'Beta'? it is not the same as Alpha a()

Comment: @Stefano, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) has an example just like this, but without the name. Yours just uses the alternative syntax `type(name)` to declare a parameter.

Comment: Thank you @chris, it's the first time I run into this error and I didn't know about Most vexing parse. 
Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @Stefano: you'd add parenthesis in the appropriate place: `Alpha alpha((Beta(d)));`. The one things which _might_ make it not a duplicate (but that's not what the question is about) is that you should really use a forwarding constructor: `Alpha(double d): Alpha(Beta(d)) {}`.